# The existence of a linear map onto an affine algebraic set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, $X\subset K^n$ be an affine algebraic set and $I$ be the ideal generated by all polynomials in $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ that vanish on $X$.

Prove that there exists a linear subspace $L$ of $K^n$ and a linear map of $K^n$ onto $L$ that maps $X$ onto $L$.

I have already proved the hint, which states that if $B/A$ is integral and $K$ is an algebraically closed field then a ring homomorphism from $A$ to $K$ can be extended to $B$ to $K$. My thought of this problem is to use Noether's normalization theorem, so there exists $K[y_1,\cdots,y_m]\subset K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I$ where the extension is integral and $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ are linear combinations of $x_1,\cdots,x_n$. Then $L$ should be this $m$-dimensional subspace of $K^n$. But I am not sure how to construct the map. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost done the problem. So you have the commutative diagram 
[image]

The bottom arrow is integral and hence induces a surjection from $mSpec(\Gamma V)\rightarrow mSpec(k[Y_1,..Y_m])$
Going to the antiequivalent category of varieties we have the commutative diagram [image]

The map $k^n \rightarrow k^m$ is a linear map since each co-ordinate in $k^m$ namely $Y_i$ is a linear combination of the co-ordinates in $k^n$ namely $X_1,...,X_n$ and $V \rightarrow k^m$ is surjective by the discussion above. The argument is now complete.